# make Attributes consistent for all Elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file with inconsistent attributes for all the elements like this

```
<Elem1 Attrib1="1" Attrib2="2"/>
<Elem2 Attrib1="21" Attrib3="23"/>
<Elem3 Attrib2="32" Attrib3="33" Attrib4="34"/>
```

I want to transform this file so that all elements have same number of attributes like this

```
<Elem1 Attrib1="1" Attrib2="2" Attrib3="" Attrib4=""/>
<Elem2 Attrib1="21" Attrib2="" Attrib3="23" Attrib4=""/>
<Elem3 Attrib1="" Attrib2="32" Attrib3="33" Attrib4="34"/>
```

Can this be achieved with XSLT?

Comment: I think, its possible. What have you tried & where did you got struck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a generic approach in XSLT 1.0. It contains some extra logic to ensure that the attributes are all in the same order:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <xsl:key name="kAttr" match="@*" use="name()" />
  <xsl:variable name="distinctAttr"
                select="//@*[generate-id() = 
                             generate-id(key('kAttr', name())[1])]" />

  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$distinctAttr | @*">
        <xsl:sort select="name()" />
        <xsl:with-param name="parent" select="." />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:param name="parent" select="/.." />
    <xsl:if test="not($parent) or 
                  count(.. | $parent) = 1 or 
                  not($parent/@*[name() = name(current())])">
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, string-length() * 
                                              (2 - count($parent | ..)))"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on this input:

```
<doc>
  <Elem1 Attrib1="1" Attrib2="2"/>
  <Elem2 Attrib1="21" Attrib3="23"/>
  <Elem3 Attrib2="32" Attrib3="33" Attrib4="34"/>
</doc>
```

The result is:

```
<doc>
  <Elem1 Attrib1="1" Attrib2="2" Attrib3="" Attrib4="" />
  <Elem2 Attrib1="21" Attrib2="" Attrib3="23" Attrib4="" />
  <Elem3 Attrib1="" Attrib2="32" Attrib3="33" Attrib4="34" />
</doc>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an XSLT 2.0 option. It could probably be modified to work for XSLT 1.0.

**XML Input**

```
<doc>
    <Elem1 Attrib1="1" Attrib2="2"/>
    <Elem2 Attrib1="21" Attrib3="23"/>
    <Elem3 Attrib2="32" Attrib3="33" Attrib4="34"/>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="attrs" select="//@*/name()"/>
    <xsl:key name="kAttrs" match="@*" use="name()"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@*]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('kAttrs',$attrs)">
                <xsl:attribute name="{name(.)}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<doc>
   <Elem1 Attrib1="1" Attrib2="2" Attrib3="" Attrib4=""/>
   <Elem2 Attrib1="21" Attrib2="" Attrib3="23" Attrib4=""/>
   <Elem3 Attrib1="" Attrib2="32" Attrib3="33" Attrib4="34"/>
</doc>
```

---

Here's another XSLT 2.0 option that would be 2.0 only (this one is **MUCH** faster too):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="attrs" select="distinct-values(//@*/name())"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@*]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="$attrs">
                <xsl:attribute name="{.}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will return the same results as above (w/same input).

Comment: That is a tricky one. Adding all attributes with empty value, and replace them with existing ones. I like it. ;-)

Comment: i get following "error Expected end of the expression, found '('" at line "<xsl:variable name="attrs" select="//@*/name()"/>"

Comment: @user2071531 - Are you sure you're not using XSLT 1.0? In 1.0, you'd have to do `name(//@*)`.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of possible soultions.
Here a little bit straightforward one, assuming the list of attributes you are concerning about is well known:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Elem1|Elem2|Elem3">
        <xsl:copy >
            <xsl:attribute name="Attrib1">
                <xsl:value-of select="@Attrib1"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="Attrib2">
                <xsl:value-of select="@Attrib2"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="Attrib3">
                <xsl:value-of select="@Attrib3"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="Attrib4">
                <xsl:value-of select="@Attrib4"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <test>
        <xsl:apply-templates  />
        </test>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

**When the transformation**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Elem1|Elem2|Elem3">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:if test="@Attrib1"><xsl:attribute name="Attrib1"><xsl:value-of select="@Attrib1"/></xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="not(@Attrib1)"><xsl:attribute name="Attrib1"></xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="@Attrib2"><xsl:attribute name="Attrib2"><xsl:value-of select="@Attrib2"/></xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="not(@Attrib2)"><xsl:attribute name="Attrib2"></xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="@Attrib3"><xsl:attribute name="Attrib3"><xsl:value-of select="@Attrib3"/></xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="not(@Attrib3)"><xsl:attribute name="Attrib3"></xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="@Attrib4"><xsl:attribute name="Attrib4"><xsl:value-of select="@Attrib4"/></xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="not(@Attrib4)"><xsl:attribute name="Attrib4"></xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**runs on below XML**

```
<test>
<Elem1 Attrib1="1" Attrib2="2"/>
<Elem2 Attrib1="21" Attrib3="23"/>
<Elem3 Attrib2="32" Attrib3="33" Attrib4="34"/>
</test>
```

**gives the required output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<test>
<Elem1 Attrib1="1" Attrib2="2" Attrib3="" Attrib4=""/>
<Elem2 Attrib1="21" Attrib2="" Attrib3="23" Attrib4=""/>
<Elem3 Attrib1="" Attrib2="32" Attrib3="33" Attrib4="34"/>
</test>
```